# what is the limit of: $\lim_{t \to 0}(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}\left |f \right |^{t}(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{t}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

edit:  we are using Riemann integration and f is continuous

given:
$f:[ a , b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$f(x) \neq 0$

i need to prove that:
$\lim_{t \to 0}(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}\left |f  \right |^{t}(x)dx)^{\frac{1}{t}} = exp(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}ln\left |f  \right |(x)dx)$

i got as fat as simplifing to: $\lim_{t \to 0}(1 +\frac{t}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}ln\left |f  \right |(x)dx + O(t^{2}))^{\frac{1}{t}}$

i see it is colse to e but i cant understand how to get rid of the $O(t^{2})$

i tried to use the Squeeze theorem but i cant Squeeze the top to the e format

Comment: I assume you are using Riemann integration and that $f$ is continuous? or are we in a measure-theory workstyle?

Comment: yes, we are using Riemann integration and that f is continuous

Comment: Just for syntax, if you say 'prove : P' then P must be statement. In your title, $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\sim)^{1/t}$ is not a statement, rather a term. Please make it in form of $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\sim)^{1/t}=$some term, or change question as : What is the limit of $(\sim)^{1/t}$?

Comment: Some intuition: If $g_t(x) = (x^t-1)/t$, check that $g^{-1}_t(\int_0^1 g_t(f(x))dx = (\int_0^1 f(x)^t dx)^{1/t}$.  Then as $t \rightarrow 0$ $g_t \rightarrow \log$ and $g_t^{-1} \rightarrow \exp$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG assume that $b-a=1$ (so we dont write $1/(b-a)$ all the time). So you have reached to 
$$\lim_{t\to0} (1+t\int_a^b\log|f|+O(t^2))^{1/t}\geq\lim_{t\to0}(1+t\int_a^b\log|f|)^{1/t}=\exp(\int_a^b\log|f|).$$
To get the other estimate, prove that for any $t>0$ that is sufficiently small we have the inequality $(1+tx)^{1/t}\leq e^x$ for all $x$. Let $M>0$ such that $O(t^2)\leq Mt^2$ in your notation. Then we have for any $t>0$, small,

$$(1+t\int_a^b\log|f|+O(t^2))^{1/t} \leq(1+t\int_a^b\log|f|+Mt^2)^{1/t}\leq\exp(\int_a^b\log|f|+Mt) $$

Taking limits as $t\to0$ yields $\lim_{t\to0} (1+t\int_a^b\log|f|+O(t^2))^{1/t}\leq\exp(\int_a^b\log|f|)$ as we wanted.

Comment: thank you very much!